# How to read a file in c++ without reading every line two times

Tags: c++

I have a problem reading file by using c++.The file which contains a float number at every line as following

```
1.33
5.45
6.21
2.48
3.84
7.96
8.14
4.36
2.24
9.45
```

My code is reading and printing everyline and printing it two times.How can i fix it?

```
    string line;
    fstream inputNumbersFile("input.txt");

    if (inputNumbersFile.is_open())
    {   
        while (!inputNumbersFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inputNumbersFile, line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aside: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to see what it's doing? This is what you should start with in a problem like this. It'll probably shed some light on your issue.

Comment: I just built this with GCC 4.6.3 on Linux, using your input data, and it works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, i  have stepped through my code with debugger.And it executes geline statement two times in while loop.

Comment: Do you mean the last line empty line is printed? It works for me, especially with the fix in the answers.

Comment: I suspect you've described the output wrongly: you should just post the output rather than trying to describe it. (and also, for your input file, say whether the last line has a newline at the end or not, assuming you know how to find out)

Comment: The following code worked. I couldn't understand what's wrong! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using of `inputNumbersFile.eof()` in loop condition is a bad idea. Just replace this loop with something like

```
while (getline(inputNumbersFile, line))
    cout << line << endl;
```